# Natbib confused with same first author and year but different coauthors

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, chicago-style

I want to cite the three papers by **same first author** but different coauthors all published in the same year.
This gives me an error: the same citation without distinguishing or adding extra letter.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\title{Natbib confused with same first author and year but different coauthors}
\maketitle
 \section{Introduction}
 I want to cite the three papers by same first author but different coauthors
 all published in the same year \cite{roy_05a}, \cite{roy_05b}, \cite{roy_05c}.
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{testBib}
\end{document}
```

Here the testBib.bib

```
@article{roy_05a,
Author = {Roy, S. and Xu, S. and Yang, W.},
Journal = {New Journal},
Pages = {1333-1341},
Title = {A new paper in new journal},
Volume = {10},
Year = {2005},
}

@inProceedings{roy_05b,
Author = {Roy, S. and Xu, S. and Yang, W. and Zung, T.},
BookTitle = {4th Journal conference proceedings},
Pages = {1291 -- 1298},
Title = {Another new paper},
Volume = {18E23},
Year = {2005},
place={USA}
}
@article{roy_05c,
Author = {Roy, S. and Yang, W. and Zung, T. and Zang, J.},
Journal = {Other Journal},
Pages = {123-134},
Title = {Another new paper in new journal},
Volume = {11},
Year = {2005},
}
```

After building, this gives me

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think your setup isn't right: If you want to use the `chicago` bibliography style, you should also use the `chicago` citation management package rather than the `natbib` citation management package. With the `chicago` citation management package in use, you'll get unambiguous citation call-outs, as the screenshot below demonstrates.

By the way, the BibTeX bibliography style called `chicago` was last changed in 1992 [!] and, as such, is based on the 13th edition of "The Chicago Manual of Style". If you want a "chicago" style that's based on the *current*, i.e., 16th edition of the Chicago Manual (2010), you should look into switching to `biblatex` and using the `biblatex-chicago` package.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{testBib.bib}
@article{roy_05a,
Author = {Roy, S. and Xu, S. and Yang, W.},
Journal = {New Journal},
Pages = {1333-1341},
Title = {A new paper in new journal},
Volume = {10},
Year = {2005},
}
@inProceedings{roy_05b,
Author = {Roy, S. and Xu, S. and Yang, W. and Zung, T.},
BookTitle = {4th Journal conference proceedings},
Pages = {1291-1298},
Title = {Another new paper},
Volume = {18E23},
Year = {2005},
place={USA}
}
@article{roy_05c,
Author = {Roy, S. and Yang, W. and Zung, T. and Zang, J.},
Journal = {Other Journal},
Pages = {123-134},
Title = {Another new paper in new journal},
Volume = {11},
Year = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{chicago} % <--- new
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\begin{document}
\cite{roy_05a}

\cite{roy_05b}

\cite{roy_05c}
\bibliography{testBib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tank you Mico for answering. But , I would like to work  only with natbib package.

Comment: @layth  - You are, of corse, free to work with any citation management package you like. As you've discovered, though, `natbib` isn't the best package to go with the `chicago` bibliography style. If you insist on using `natbib`, you may want to investigate which other bibliography styles may better suit your needs.